# Parse php json to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, yii

So, I have to parse an php json into javascript.

The code looks like this:

```
$thumbnails = [];
foreach ($images as $key => $image) 
{
  $thumbnails[$image->time] = [
    'src' => MovieEntity::getImageWithPublicPath(
      $movie->id, $image->filename, 130, 0, false
    ),
    'width' => '165px',
    'height' => '95px'
  ];
}

return json_encode($thumbnails, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

and the result is:

```
{"5":{"src":"google.ro","width":"165px","height":"95px"},"7":
```

I want to take the `src`, `width` and `height` and insert them as pictures like:

```
<a href="">
  <img src="src of image" width="" height="">
</a>
```

What do I need to do? This variable in PHP is called `$thumbnails`, which returns the JSON I showed above.

```
<?php echo $thumbnails ?>
```

LE: My solution is:

```
<?= '<script>var json='.$thumbnails.'</script>' ?>
console.log(json);
```

This will return you the json in the console.

Comment: Its not duplicate. I need something different thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery: [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).

If you're using plain javascript: [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse)

```
// jQuery snipet
var thumbnails = $.parseJSON('<?php echo $thumbnails; ?>');
console.log(thumbnails.src);
console.log(thumbnails.width);
console.log(thumbnails.height);
```

Comment: If I try to use your code I got this:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: @StefanIordache there was a typo: I have written $thumnails instead of $thumbnails.
Try it now

Comment: Yea, I saw it from the beginning.
I still got this message from console.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Function.oe.parseJSON

Comment: @StefanIordache can I see what does it print your javascript code when you echo $thumbnails? try console.log('<?php echo $thumbnails; ?>') and let me see if the JSON is correct

Comment: I get the string between the quotes <?php echo $thumbnails; ?>

Comment: I tryed something different <?= '<script>var json='.$thumbnails.'</script>' ?> and when I call 'json' in console log it returns me the json

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain JavaScript.

Echo the JSON into a script tag

```
<script type="application/json" id="json">
    <?php echo $thumbnails; ?>
</script>
```

Then target it with JavaScript

```
var json = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json').innerHTML);

var img = document.querySelector('img');

img.src = json.src;
img.width = json.width;
img.height = json.height;
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, you have to request your php function by doing a get request (assume you use jQuery). After that, in the success callback, you have the data. So try something like that :

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'file.php', // your php file
   type : 'GET', // type of the HTTP request
   success : function(data){
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(obj);
   }
});
```

You can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35451767/4911780) for more informations

Comment: I have the js and php in the same file

Comment: and you can't separate in two files? or try to delete the url property in the ajax object